# can I perform a statistical test without biological replicates?

Tags: statistical-significance

I am new to statistics and have a question.
Suppose I have a test in which I have to compare the number of live cells grown in different conditions after a period of time and I don't have any biological replicates as I performed the test only once.

For example, the data would be something like this:
condition A = 500 cells;
condition B = 1200 cells;
condition C = 700 cells

Can I perform a statistical test to compare them?
Can I count the cells multiple times or ask someone else to count them and then perform ANOVA or t-test?

Comment: What is your outcome (i.e., the dependent variable)? What do you measure for each cell? Could you give more biological context (your experiment) so that we can try to see what is the outcome of the experiment?

Comment: the outcome is the number of the cells for example we treat cells with a drug and count the cells that resisted it and stayed alive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very important thing that statistical methods can give you is a principled approach to generalising from a dataset with uncertainty. For your data you can be certain that there were more cells counted in condition B than in A or C, but you cannot be certain that condition B would routinely be associated with more cells. In other words, you have very little of interest to say about the biological system because the uneven distribution of cells between the conditions may be nothing more than natural variability or counting noise.

Statistical methods allow you to calibrate the size of differences relative to the variability. If the difference is large relative to the variability (or noise) then the difference is unlikely to be simply the result of that variability. But to use the statistical calibration you need to be able to estimate the variability that is relevant to the type of inference that you wish to draw.

If you were to have a sample of people re-do your counts then you would be able to estimate the human-related variability of counts of cells and thus be potentially in a position to say how likely any observed differences in counts was due to counting errors (variability, noise). However, that type of inference has very little utility in a biological study unless the study concern the variability or human counting.

If you want to make an inference about the association of conditions and cell counts —perhaps even inferences about the causes of differences in cell counts— then you need to calibrate the differences using the variability of the association of conditions and counts. Basically you need replicates of the count and condition pairs.

Comment: Thank you very much for this thoughtful answer. This helped me a lot.